# webkit-backdrop-filter not working in React.js

Tags: css, reactjs, webkit, blur

I'm working on React website, trying to add a blur to a container with a span of text. For whatever reason, the blur will not show. I cannot figure out why.

Any help would be great!

HTML:

```
<div className={styles.CardContentContainer}>
                <div className={styles.ProjectTitle1}>
                  <span>Real Estate</span>
                </div>
...
```

CSS:

```
.ProjectTitle1 {
    padding-right: 9px;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: -84px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: #aa1a18;
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    box-shadow: var(--main-top-shadow);
    box-shadow: var(--main-shadow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not a React problem, note that the backdrop-filter property acts as a background, so if you add a background color to your element, what will be seen will be the color and you will not notice the blur effect. But if you want to use a background color, what you should do is use a low opacity percentage.

You can see the following example as a reference to what I am trying to explain.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
.ProjectTitle1 {
    padding-right: 9px;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 30px;
    background-color: #aa1a18;
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    box-shadow: var(--main-top-shadow);
    box-shadow: var(--main-shadow);
}
/* without the background color */
.ProjectTitle1-noBGColor {
    padding-right: 9px;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top:40px;
    left: 30px;
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    box-shadow: var(--main-top-shadow);
    box-shadow: var(--main-shadow);
}

/* background color with low opacity */
.ProjectTitle1-BGColorOpacity {
    padding-right: 9px;
    padding-left: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 30px;
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    box-shadow: var(--main-top-shadow);
    box-shadow: var(--main-shadow);
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" width="230px" height="250px">
        <div class="ProjectTitle1">
            <span>Real Estate</span>
        </div>
        <div class="ProjectTitle1-noBGColor">
            <span>Real Estate</span>
        </div>
        <div class="ProjectTitle1-BGColorOpacity">
            <span>Real Estate</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body> 

</html>
```